# Delete comments in file Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to delete comments in file, like:

```
/* this*/
/*this
*
*
*/
//And this
```

and write to another file.
i used this regex:

```
 public String delComments(String input){
         String noComments = input.replaceAll("//.*|(\"(?:\\\\[^\"]|\\\\\"|.)*?\")|(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", "$1 ");
        return noComments;
```

and method of reading

```
String line = null;
    FileReader fileReader =
            new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePathNoComm);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
       delComments(line);
        bw.write(line);
    }
    bw.close();
```

but it doesn't work.
What do i do wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work", and don't forget to include your step-by-step debug observations.

Comment: New text file stays with comments, that's what i mean

Comment: You forgot to include your step-by-step debug observations.

Comment: BTW, `delComments` doesn't change the input argument, but simply returns a new one. You should by the least do something with that returned value. For example, `bw.write(delComments(line))`. Had you attempted to perform even the tiniest debug effort, you would have immediately noticed that problem.

Comment: The approach is too error prone.  You need a library that can parse language construct.  Eclipse ADT could do that.

Comment: How will you be deleting comments. any particular editor or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet:

```
public static String delComments(String content){
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("/\\*.*?\\*/|/{2,}[^\\n]*", Pattern.DOTALL);

    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(content);
    return matcher.replaceAll("");
}
```

It should remove all comments.

I have sample input file:

```
package com.company;

/**
 * Created by XXX on 4/3/16.
 */

public class Test {
    // Will fix it later

    int x = 0; // declaration.
}
```

After getting cleaned, it will emit:

```
package com.company;


public class Test {


    int x = 0; 
}
```